# Can a reverse-proxy server take HTTPS request and forward to a web server via HTTP?

Tags: nginx, deployment, webserver, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

If I have a reverse proxy server (say Nginx) running on an SSL-certified domain name, can this proxy server takes an HTTPS request and forwards it to a regular web server (say gunicorn) via HTTP without creating errors like "blocked with mixed content"?

If the answer to the above question is "no", is the only way to forward an HTTPS request from a reverse-proxy server to another regular server (hosted on some IP address) is to buy a domain name for the regular server and get it an SSL certificate?

I tried googling this but I can't find a clear answer. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [SSL termination](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/) is one of the main use cases of a reverse proxy. So yes, this is possible.